# How to extract Python 3.5+ from installer?

Tags: windows, installation, python, installer

In versions *lower* than 3.5.0 there was a `.MSI` installer for Windows, which had a really nice hidden option. That option looked like this:

```
msiexec.exe /a "file.msi" /qb /L*V "file.log" ALLUSERS=0 TARGETDIR="target" CURRENTDIRECTORY="%~dp0" <additional options>
```

which basically allows me to ignore admin rights, because the MSI turns to some kind of installer for whole network, thus the permission workaround.

With Python 3.5.0 was introduced a new `.EXE` installer, which has `.MSI` files packed in itself, you can get them out with:

```
python-3.5.0.exe /layout [optional target directory]
```

yet there's a really annoying thing going around with this solution. When I do this, the `.MSI` files have a `-d.msi` suffix and when I manually unpack it with the `msiexec` command above, ***every file*** has that suffix too, which makes it a *completely damaged* installation. Renaming the files isn't really an option as each file has `-d.<file ext>`, not `-d.msi.<file ext>` suffix, so it's too hard to rename it in a simple way with tools such as Batch, unless I want to check for multiple cases (e.g. folders).

Is there any way how to extract the content of the installer to a separate folder, like it was possible before **without** any additional stuff put into `Programs and features`, such as `Python 3.5.0 (64bit)` or simlar?

Or other question - is there any way how to forbid the installer to access `Programs and features`, shut it from asking admin privileges and registry at all?

It's quite useful if I want to have multiple python installations not bound to anything at all with testing as its main purpose. Note, that I have no intention to use python launcher (that `py.exe` thing), virtualenv or any other alternative "solution" as every of them allows me to install only a ***single*** Python installation of the same version and/or is too big for quick usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently casual Python installer since 3.5 has the MSIs I require *embeded* and they won't come out. There's however the web-installer for each Python and with that one you can do the same thing and get a working Python installation:

```
python-3.5.0-webinstall.exe /layout <folder>
```

This downloads the `Release` MSIs files (not `Debug` or `PDB` only). Then you'll need to filter the files that have `_d.msi` and `_pdb.msi` suffix, which is trivial with Batch now and you end up with this structure:

```
core.msi
dev.msi
doc.msi
exe.msi
launcher.msi
lib.msi
path.msi
pip.msi
python-3.6.0-webinstall.exe
tcltk.msi
test.msi
tools.msi
```

and quite a lot of VS redistributables. Depending on your needs you may want to delete `.exe`, `.msu`(redists), `_d.msi`, `_pdb.msi` files in your working directory. The rest are `Release` files and files that extend the interpreter functionality such as launcher(`py.exe`), path(probably just permanently puts python to `PATH`), etc.

If you run each of them with this:

```
msiexec.exe /a <file> targetdir=<folder>
```

you get a working portable Python installation. Note that such thing is [not officially supported](http://bugs.python.org/issue29231).

Answer (score 4):

A sub-folder now contain all the `.msi` files:
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/amd64/

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [the previously linked bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue29231), the [nuget packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/python) are more suitable for unpacking manually - they're actually zip files.

The Python 3.8.1 nuget contains a `tools` subfolder which contains the actual Python installation (with a normal `python.exe`, `pythonw.exe`, `Lib/`, `include/` etc); things outside that folder are metadata.

Comment: that works. but one problem: how to add tkinter? I have search the solution for embedded python, which copies files from another installation from official python. What I do not wanna to install? because if I have installed one there is no need to use a zipped one.